# script for duplicate target in Xcode project

Tags: shell, xcode5

I want to duplicate target of Xcode project with command line, I have searched a lot but not found any solution. I don't have any idea how to write script to duplicate target.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see how a script will do what you want.  You'll have to do it manually.

Comment: Is there any documentation where it is mentioned that we can not duplicate target?

Comment: Doubtful; documentation normally covers features, not lack of features.

Comment: Ok thanks, But i need proof :)

Comment: Why down voted? Please give me the reason

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see the code, it worked for me:

```
tell active workspace document
    set my_project to (get first project)
    tell my_project


        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke "d" using {command down}
            delay 0.5
            tell application process "Xcode"
                --delay 1.0E-3

                click button "Duplicate Only" of window 1


            end tell

        end tell

    end tell
end tell
end tell
```